# PHP 0 of type string > then 0 of type string equals true?

Tags: php, type-conversion, switch-statement

Hello I have the following code and its baffling me. How is it hitting this case?

```
<?php 

  $concept = '0';

    switch ($concept) {

        case ($concept > '0'):
            $score  = 'Y';
            break;

    } 


?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `switch` docs:

> Note:
>   Note that switch/case does loose comparision.

[Check the falsy-ness for `'0'`](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose), it's awful, I know. Your case evaluates to `false` and, as you can see in the linked tbl, `('0' == false) === true`.

I'd change your `switch` statement to:

```
switch(true)
{
    case ($concept >'0'):
        echo 'Impossible';
    break;
}
```

Also, like the docs say: `switch` is a loop-like structure that performs loose comparison. You can't choose the comparison operator yourself. If you want to check the value of `$concept` against an array of cases, you'll have to write:

```
switch($concept)
{
   case '0': echo 'a zero string'; break;
   case '1': echo 'a 1 concept'; break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your switch is on $concept; your case is ($concept > '0'), which evaluates to FALSE, so effectively you're saying `case FALSE:`; That FALSE is compared against the switch condition ($concept), which is '0'; loose typing gives a comparison of '0' against FALSE, which evaluates to TRUE; therefore the case is met.

I don't thing you really understand what a switch statement actually does; but it isn't simply an alternative to if statements

Comment: So the alternative would be using if statements?

Comment: In this case, an if statement would be a lot easier, and the code would be more logically readable

Comment: Thanks Mark for your answer, I have upvoted it but I went for the other answer as its what I need. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

It works like this.

```
<?php 

  $concept = '0';  // 1. This is a string

    switch ($concept) { // 3. boolean FALSE is compared to $concept, 
                        //    which forces $concept to be cast to boolean,
                        //    thus the comparison is FALSE == FALSE which equals TRUE

        case ($concept > '0'):  // 2. ($concept > '0') evaluates to boolean FALSE
            $score  = 'Y';
            break;

    }
```

Note the numbers that I've added in the comments to show the order of how things are evaluated. (Very simplistic).

What you can do to avoid type issues is something like this:

```
<?php 

  $concept = '0';

    switch (TRUE) {

        case ($concept > '0'):
            $score  = 'Y';
            break;

    }
```

What this does is compares all the case conditions to TRUE, and works more like you would expect. Note that this usage of switch is a little unconventional, but can avoid some type casting issues in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

It compares $concept with the result of $concept > '0'

```
$concept = '0' // '0' == false
$concept > '0' // '0'>'0' == false
```

your statemant is equal to:

```
switch (false){
  case (false):
    $score  = 'Y';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your case is matching because `false==false` How is this happening first take your switch condition which is `$concept` with an initial value of string "0".

Then lets take your case statement which is `$concept > 0` this expression evaluates to `false` and are evaluated prior to the switch block execution because switch statements matches the block values with the calling value.

Then when the match is being made your `$concept` value = "0" is being converted to a boolean value `false`.

so `false==false`

Comment: He gets `true` instead of `false`.

Comment: @HamZa is my writing better this time